# Trying to get property of non-object - laravel mongodb

Tags: ajax, mongodb, laravel

I am using laravel with mongodb, While i am getting result, it shows "Trying to get property of non-object", what is wrong with my code?

```
Controller query:
$fetch_qry = Auditproject::where('projectid','=',$request->proj_id)->where('siteengineerid','=',$request->cont_id)->where('sub_id','=',$loggedin)->first();
$audit_pid=$fetch_qry->_id;

My ajax:
 datastring="mytext="+displayed_tree1+"&mytext1="+selected_node1+"&proj_id="+pj_id+"&cont_id="+site_engineer_id+"&wbs_display="+res;

              $.ajax
              ({
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType : 'json',
                  async:true,
                  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                      var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
                      if (token) {
                          return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
                      }
                  },
                  url: "{{ URL::to('store_wbs_siteeng') }}",
                  data: datastring,
                  success:function(data){

                      return "Assigned Successfully";
                  },
                  failure: function() {alert("Error!");}
              });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always do the check if your query returns an object or `null`:

```
$audit_pid = is_null($fetch_qry) ? $defaultId : $fetch_qry->_id;
```

Or:

```
if (is_null($fetch_qry)) {
    return response()->json(['Result is empty']);
}
```

When the result is `null` it simply means there is now row in DB which has `projectid = $request->proj_id`, `siteengineerid  = $request->cont_id` and `sub_id = $loggedin`

Comment: Thanks, here what is "$defaultId"

Comment: @MuMuthukumar it's just an example. You can define it as `0` and then check with JS and if it's `0`, display some error message or something.